# How to programatically set the post title of a CPT on wp-admin

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-admin

I've been playing with custom post types & custom fields, using a combination of the `types` plugin and the `advanced custom fields` plugin, also having done the same manually.

Occasionally I want to create a CPT where a `title` would be inappropriate - for example, an FAQ where I want two fields labelled `Question` and `Answer`. This does work without a title, however they all get saved as `(No Title)`.

What I'd like to do is either set the `title` to the value of the `Question` custom field, or somehow define my own `title` field that I can label as I like.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to acheive this?

Comment: Why not use the title rather than the question field for the actual question?

Comment: @StephenHarris because I can't label the title field as a 'Question', it would be unclear to the user what to do. As I mentioned in the question, if anyone can tell me how to relabel that then that's what I would use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `enter_title_here` filter:

```
    add_filter('enter_title_here','wpse51871_alter_title_label',10,2);
    function wpse51871_alter_title_label($label, $post){
        if( 'question' == get_post_type($post) )
            $label = __('enter question here', 'my-plugin-text-domain');

        return $label;
    }
```

Comment: that's prefect, thanks! one other solution I was playing with was a bit of javascript to hide the title & update the value but this is much more elegant. thanks for sharing :)